# Calculate seconds between dates and times contained in a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I need your help to calculate the seconds between a rainfall event and the next, each of them contained in a data.frame structured in (`$Date $Time $Rain`). The events are already in chronological order, numbered sequentially (`001, 002, 003, ....`) and all organized together in a list `RAINWATER_EVENTS` of data.frames like the following:

```
RAINWATER_EVENTS (large list of data.frames)
  001:
         $Date       $Time       $Rain
    [1]  01/01/14    0:10:00     0.75 
    [2]  01/01/14    0:20:00     1.00
    [3]  01/01/14    0:30:00     1.20
    [4]  01/01/14    0:40:00     1.10
    [5]  01/01/14    0:50:00     0.80
    [6]  01/01/14    1:00:00     0.21
    [7]  01/01/14    1:10:00     0.18 (END TIME 001)

  002:
         $Date      $Time       $Rain
    [1]  06/28/14   17:40:00     0.6  (START TIME 002)
    [2]  06/28/14   17:50:00     2.4
    [3]  06/28/14   18:00:00     7.4
    [4]  06/28/14   18:10:00     0.2  (END TIME 002)

  003:
         $Date      $Time       $Rain
    [1]  08/31/14   21:10:00     1.0  (START TIME 003)
    [2]  08/31/14   21:20:00     9.0
    [3]  08/31/14   21:30:00     0.6
    [4]  08/31/14   21:40:00     0.4
    [5]  08/31/14   21:50:00     0.3

  004:
  ...
```

The result that I would like to have is a vector containing the time in seconds that elapses between each event in the list of data.frames, for example:

```
RESULT: vector()

   15438600  = Time in seconds between END TIME 001 and START TIME 002   
   5540400   = Time in seconds between END TIME 002 and START TIME 003
    .....                 ......                      .....
```

For example in Matlab there is  the function `e = etime (v2, v1)` which calculates the number of seconds between two date vectors or matrices of date vectors v1 and v2, or in Excel the formula of the seconds that elapse is as follows:

```
((finish_date+finish_time)-(start_date+start_time))*24*60*60
```

but I don't know which to use in R (if it exists), could you give me some suggestions? thank you very much.

**EDIT**: the solution suggested by @r2evans using `difftime` and `POSIXt` works perfectly in both variants, but in pasting the date and time, something does not work correctly for one of the 217 rain events, despite being built exactly like all the others. The problematic event `111` is the following:

```
111:
     $Date     $Time     $Rain
1   03/25/17 20:00:00     0.2
2   03/25/17 20:10:00     0.0
3   03/25/17 20:20:00     0.0
4   03/25/17 20:30:00     0.2
5   03/25/17 20:40:00     0.2
6   03/25/17 20:50:00     0.4
7   03/25/17 21:00:00     0.2
8   03/25/17 21:10:00     0.2
9   03/25/17 21:20:00     0.0
10  03/25/17 21:30:00     0.0
11  03/25/17 21:40:00     0.0
12  03/25/17 21:50:00     0.4
13  03/25/17 22:00:00     1.0
14  03/25/17 22:10:00     1.0
15  03/25/17 22:20:00     0.2
16  03/25/17 22:30:00     0.4
17  03/25/17 22:40:00     0.0
18  03/25/17 22:50:00     0.4
19  03/25/17 23:00:00     0.2
20  03/25/17 23:10:00     0.0
21  03/25/17 23:20:00     0.0
22  03/25/17 23:30:00     0.0
23  03/25/17 23:40:00     0.0
24  03/25/17 23:50:00     0.0
25  03/26/17  0:00:00     0.0
26  03/26/17  0:10:00     0.0
27  03/26/17  0:20:00     0.0
28  03/26/17  0:30:00     0.0
29  03/26/17  0:40:00     0.0
30  03/26/17  0:50:00     0.0
31  03/26/17  1:00:00     0.0
32  03/26/17  1:10:00     0.0
33  03/26/17  1:20:00     0.0
34  03/26/17  1:30:00     0.0
35  03/26/17  1:40:00     0.0
36  03/26/17  1:50:00     0.2
37  03/26/17  2:00:00     0.0
38  03/26/17  2:10:00     0.0
39  03/26/17  2:20:00     0.4
40  03/26/17  2:30:00     0.2
41  03/26/17  2:40:00     0.2
42  03/26/17  2:50:00     0.6
43  03/26/17  3:00:00     0.2
44  03/26/17  3:10:00     0.8
45  03/26/17  3:20:00     0.6
46  03/26/17  3:30:00     0.2
47  03/26/17  3:40:00     0.0
48  03/26/17  3:50:00     0.2
49  03/26/17  4:00:00     0.2
50  03/26/17  4:10:00     0.2
51  03/26/17  4:20:00     0.2
52  03/26/17  4:30:00     0.4
53  03/26/17  4:40:00     0.4
54  03/26/17  4:50:00     0.2
55  03/26/17  5:00:00     0.4
56  03/26/17  5:10:00     0.6
57  03/26/17  5:20:00     0.4
58  03/26/17  5:30:00     0.2
59  03/26/17  5:40:00     0.2
60  03/26/17  5:50:00     0.0
61  03/26/17  6:00:00     0.2
62  03/26/17  6:10:00     0.0
63  03/26/17  6:20:00     0.0
64  03/26/17  6:30:00     0.2
65  03/26/17  6:40:00     0.0
66  03/26/17  6:50:00     0.2
67  03/26/17  7:00:00     0.0
68  03/26/17  7:10:00     0.2
69  03/26/17  7:20:00     0.0
70  03/26/17  7:30:00     0.0
71  03/26/17  7:40:00     0.0
72  03/26/17  7:50:00     0.0
73  03/26/17  8:00:00     0.0
74  03/26/17  8:10:00     0.2
75  03/26/17  8:20:00     0.0
76  03/26/17  8:30:00     0.0
77  03/26/17  8:40:00     0.0
78  03/26/17  8:50:00     0.0
79  03/26/17  9:00:00     0.0
80  03/26/17  9:10:00     0.2
81  03/26/17  9:20:00     0.0
82  03/26/17  9:30:00     0.0
83  03/26/17  9:40:00     0.0
84  03/26/17  9:50:00     0.2
85  03/26/17 10:00:00     0.2
86  03/26/17 10:10:00     0.0
87  03/26/17 10:20:00     0.0
88  03/26/17 10:30:00     0.0
89  03/26/17 10:40:00     0.0
90  03/26/17 10:50:00     0.0
91  03/26/17 11:00:00     0.0
92  03/26/17 11:10:00     0.0
93  03/26/17 11:20:00     0.0
94  03/26/17 11:30:00     0.0
95  03/26/17 11:40:00     0.0
96  03/26/17 11:50:00     0.0
97  03/26/17 12:00:00     0.0
98  03/26/17 12:10:00     0.0
99  03/26/17 12:20:00     0.0
100 03/26/17 12:30:00     0.0
101 03/26/17 12:40:00     0.0
102 03/26/17 12:50:00     0.0
103 03/26/17 13:00:00     0.0
104 03/26/17 13:10:00     0.0
105 03/26/17 13:20:00     0.0
106 03/26/17 13:30:00     0.0
107 03/26/17 13:40:00     0.0
108 03/26/17 13:50:00     0.0
109 03/26/17 14:00:00     0.0
110 03/26/17 14:10:00     0.0
111 03/26/17 14:20:00     0.0
112 03/26/17 14:30:00     0.0
113 03/26/17 14:40:00     0.0
114 03/26/17 14:50:00     0.0
115 03/26/17 15:00:00     0.0
116 03/26/17 15:10:00     0.0
117 03/26/17 15:20:00     0.0
118 03/26/17 15:30:00     0.0
119 03/26/17 15:40:00     0.0
120 03/26/17 15:50:00     0.0
121 03/26/17 16:00:00     0.0
122 03/26/17 16:10:00     0.0
123 03/26/17 16:20:00     0.0
124 03/26/17 16:30:00     0.0
125 03/26/17 16:40:00     0.0
126 03/26/17 16:50:00     0.0
127 03/26/17 17:00:00     0.0
128 03/26/17 17:10:00     0.0
129 03/26/17 17:20:00     0.0
130 03/26/17 17:30:00     0.0
131 03/26/17 17:40:00     0.0
132 03/26/17 17:50:00     0.0
133 03/26/17 18:00:00     0.0
134 03/26/17 18:10:00     0.0
135 03/26/17 18:20:00     0.0
136 03/26/17 18:30:00     0.0
137 03/26/17 18:40:00     0.2
138 03/26/17 18:50:00     0.0
139 03/26/17 19:00:00     0.0
140 03/26/17 19:10:00     0.0
141 03/26/17 19:20:00     0.0
142 03/26/17 19:30:00     0.2
```

and the result data.frame created reports the following "hole" in correspondence with event `111`:

```
        start                 end               gap
...      ....       ....     ....     ....    ....    ....
105 2016-11-24 12:40:00 2016-11-26 01:30:00  460800 secs
106 2017-02-03 02:30:00 2017-02-03 19:30:00 6159000 secs
107 2017-02-04 10:10:00 2017-02-04 14:10:00  128400 secs
108 2017-02-05 10:40:00 2017-02-06 06:30:00  159600 secs
109 2017-02-27 18:50:00 2017-02-28 07:40:00 1976400 secs
110 2017-03-04 10:20:00 2017-03-04 14:20:00  415800 secs
111                <NA>                <NA>      NA secs
112 2017-04-26 05:50:00 2017-04-28 04:30:00      NA secs
113 2017-05-01 10:20:00 2017-05-02 04:10:00  512400 secs
114 2017-05-02 17:30:00 2017-05-03 04:20:00  151200 secs
115 2017-05-06 14:00:00 2017-05-06 22:00:00  361800 secs
116 2017-05-09 15:50:00 2017-05-09 16:10:00  267000 secs
117 2017-06-06 13:20:00 2017-06-06 14:20:00 2413800 secs
118 2017-06-08 11:20:00 2017-06-08 12:00:00  168000 secs
119 2017-06-25 06:10:00 2017-06-25 06:50:00 1452600 secs
120 2017-06-28 14:40:00 2017-06-28 17:50:00  301200 secs
121 2017-06-29 13:20:00 2017-06-29 20:50:00  108600 secs
122 2017-07-10 21:40:00 2017-07-10 22:10:00  982200 secs
123 2017-07-14 00:40:00 2017-07-14 03:20:00  279600 secs
124 2017-07-21 20:20:00 2017-07-21 21:40:00  680400 secs
...    ...      ...       ...     .. ..     .. .   . . .
215 2019-12-13 03:10:00 2019-12-13 12:30:00  119400 secs
216 2019-12-19 16:10:00 2019-12-21 12:10:00  723600 secs
217 2019-12-22 02:30:00 2019-12-22 05:30:00  220800 secs
```

Could anyone tell me what the problem may depend on? Dates and times are in chronological order with scan every 10 minutes. Thanks so much

Comment: to facilitate test of solution, can you provide the result of dput(RAINWATER_EVENTS[1:3])

Comment: R has `difftime` and `diff.POSIXt` which will do that, the former allowing for setting units (otherwise they are automatic, not always `"secs"`). However, they require operation on `POSIXt` objects, not separate strings. You'll need to `paste` the strings and convert with `as.POSIXct` before they'll be "times".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
RAINWATER %>%
  bind_rows(., .id = "x") %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(start = min(Timestamp), end = max(Timestamp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(gap = difftime(end, dplyr::lag(start, default = NA), units = "secs"))
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   x     start               end                 gap          
#   <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>       
# 1 1     2014-01-01 00:10:00 2014-01-01 01:10:00       NA secs
# 2 2     2014-06-28 17:40:00 2014-06-28 18:10:00 15440400 secs
# 3 3     2014-08-31 21:10:00 2014-08-31 21:50:00  5544600 secs
```

### base R

```r
grps <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(RAINWATER, function(x) {
    ts <- as.POSIXct(paste(x$Date, x$Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
    data.frame(start = min(ts), end = max(ts))
  }))
grps$gap <- difftime(grps$end, c(c.POSIXct(NA), grps$start[-nrow(grps)]), units = "secs")
grps
```

---

Data

```r
RAINWATER <- list(
  read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Date        Time        Rain
01/01/14    0:10:00     0.75 
01/01/14    0:20:00     1.00
01/01/14    0:30:00     1.20
01/01/14    0:40:00     1.10
01/01/14    0:50:00     0.80
01/01/14    1:00:00     0.21
01/01/14    1:10:00     0.18"),
read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Date       Time        Rain
06/28/14   17:40:00     0.6
06/28/14   17:50:00     2.4
06/28/14   18:00:00     7.4
06/28/14   18:10:00     0.2"),
read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Date       Time         Rain
08/31/14   21:10:00     1.0
08/31/14   21:20:00     9.0
08/31/14   21:30:00     0.6
08/31/14   21:40:00     0.4
08/31/14   21:50:00     0.3")
)
```

---

Not shown in the question, but there is a problem with your timestamps, but it depends on what timezone you use. Seeing an `NA` in a summary field typically means there was a timestamp that did not parse correctly. This can happen when either the string is malformed, or when the date/time combination is illegal (think: daylight savings time, the gift that keeps on giving).

First, a quick demo of your data. I'll use `dplyr` because it gives me rapid demonstration:

```r
EVENTI %>%
  bind_rows(., .id = "x") %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(DATA, ORA), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  filter(is.na(Timestamp))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   x     DATA     ORA     PIOGGIA Timestamp          
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <dttm>             
# 1 149   03/11/18 2:00:00       0 NA                 
# 2 149   03/11/18 2:10:00       0 NA                 
# 3 149   03/11/18 2:20:00       0 NA                 
# 4 149   03/11/18 2:30:00       0 NA                 
# 5 149   03/11/18 2:40:00       0 NA                 
# 6 149   03/11/18 2:50:00       0 NA
```

Notice how this is in group `149`? Yeah, it's sensitive to the time zone. Since you mentioned Italy, I'll try with `tz="Europe/Rome"`

```r
EVENTI %>%
#   bind_rows(., .id = "x") %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
#   mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(DATA, ORA), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Rome")) %>%
  filter(is.na(Timestamp))
+ > 
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   x     DATA     ORA     PIOGGIA Timestamp          
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <dttm>             
# 1 111   03/26/17 2:00:00     0   NA                 
# 2 111   03/26/17 2:10:00     0   NA                 
# 3 111   03/26/17 2:20:00     0.4 NA                 
# 4 111   03/26/17 2:30:00     0.2 NA                 
# 5 111   03/26/17 2:40:00     0.2 NA                 
# 6 111   03/26/17 2:50:00     0.6 NA
```

(Hint to a possible solution, *depending on your data source*: use `tz="UTC"` and there are no problems.)

Which explains why you're having problems with a different group. Why do these not parse? Well, in my tz (`"US/Pacific"`), daylight savings in 2018 occurred on March 11 ([ref](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa?year=2018)), which explains why mine failed with `149`. My guess is that your timezone shifted on the 26th.

Truth be told, this is not clearly definitive: the reference says Mar 25 (Rome's 2018 DST, [ref](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/italy/rome?year=2018)), this fails on Mar 26, so ... it depends wholly on where your data is from. Ultimately, though, since it occurs on/near common DST dates that year and lasts an hour, it is almost certainly a TZ and/or DST problem.

Three ways to remedy this:

1. If you determine (or assume) that the timezone is `"UTC"`, then the problem does not happen. Fix your code to read:

   ```r
   ## tidyverse
     mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")) %>%
   ## base
       ts <- as.POSIXct(paste(x$Date, x$Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
   ```
2. If you know that it is not UTC or don't trust that solution, then ... you should determine what really happened and fix the data. To see what I mean, if you use `na.rm=T` as in number 3, then you have a whole hour of data that you are dismissing. This means that whatever is logged at `03:00:00` really happened at `04:00:00`. A quick hack might just add an hour on this day, but perhaps you should be looking at all times between Mar 25 and Oct 28, 2018 (and likely similar issues in other years).

   This suggests a little sleuthing into what created the data, and try to reverse-engineer what it got wrong. Did it ignore DST completely, or just use a wrong day? The former is much easier to accommodate, the latter is ... a problem.
3. ***This is an incomplete fix.*** Please, I'm not kidding, please look into numbers 1 and 2. If you go with this solution, your data will be wrong by an hour for much of the year, but it will stop "complaining" (which does not make it right).

   Add `na.rm=TRUE` to your min/max calls, as in

   ```r
   ## tidyverse
     summarize(start = min(Timestamp, na.rm = TRUE), end = max(Timestamp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   ## base
       data.frame(start = min(ts, na.rm = TRUE), end = max(ts, na.rm = TRUE))
   ```

Comment: It works perfectly! I only tested the base R solution that you suggested as I am not very good at R and it seems easier to understand. Thank you very much for your clear and precise help.

Comment: thanks again for your solution, I would just like to ask you for a quick help since one of the events (111 of 217 to give an idea) does not report the start and end date and therefore the calculation of the seconds. This event is exactly like the others starting on 03/25/17 20:00:00 and ending 03/26/17 19:30:00, but I can't really understand why it is skipped. Can you suggest what to check? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know, can you give a hint? What is the data, what is the error, what is the incorrect output, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I edited the question by inserting the whole event 111 which returns the problem and the result I get from applying your algorithm.

Comment: I have rerun my code (both dplyr and base) with 111 added, and I get no `NA`s. Are you certain that `"111"` is the 111th in the list? While the range of timestamps does fall in line with where I would expect the `NA` row to be, perhaps there's another one that's causing problems. If you name the 111th frame as `x` and run the two inner-most lines of code `ts <-` and `data.frame(...)`, does it work?

Comment: Thank you for your availability and patience, the 111 event I checked and corresponds, I try to attach a link containing the list of events in .rds, this is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdGJekaG7k_3bPVypWYIDYnthGEN2F-F/view?usp=sharing PS: the list is called "EVENTI" while Date, time and rain are in Italian, therefore DATA, ORA and PIOGGIA

Comment: I tried your last suggestion, applying only the two lines of code to frame 111 and actually between the positions 37 and 42 of the event there are NA, perhaps for this reason the POSIXt does not work well. Thanks again for your help

Comment: See my edit. Your problem is not minor, but at least you know what it is now.

Comment: See another edit ... if UTC makes sense *logically* based on your data source, then it works without complaining.

Comment: You are a genius, I would have thought about i at least until the return of the next solar hour! Seriously thank you very much for your precise explanation, I was thinking of cutting the data between 2:00 and 2:50 on 03/26/2017 and cumulating the value of rain cut at 3:00 on the same day. In this way I recreate the EVENTS list without that problem (fortunately it is the only one since evidently no other rain event between 2014 and 2019 happened in Milan in these hourly transitions). One last super quick thing, is it possible to change the time format in the `grps` frame from y-m-d to m/d/y?

Comment: R doesn't store dates in `m/d/y`: when it shows a `Date` or `POSIXt` (timestamp) on the console, the only things it references are found in `print.POSIXct`, `print.POSIXlt`, `format.POSIXct`, and `format.POSIXlt`. Bottom line, by default it looks at `options("digits.secs")`, nothing more (though locale will affect it, I believe, not much experience here). This means that for *showing data*, you can only affect the number of digits in the seconds. For *reporting* (plots, reports), you can use `format` to make it look however you like, though it loses its numeric properties when you do that.

Comment: Thanks again for your kind help, I managed to fix the data and get the result I wanted!